# What does SqlDbType convert to in Oracle?

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2015

I can't find anything on this.  I'm converting some code in C# to use an Oracle back end instead of SQL Server.  So, I've got a line of code like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Effective_Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtEffDate.Text;
```

A quick search found "OracleDbType" in some sample code, but that isn't available to me in Intellisense.  I see an "OracleType", is this the proper one to use?  Also, what do the old SqlDbTypes convert to?  I.E., SqlDbType.Char would be *what* when using an Oracle DB?

Comment: I think it's OracleDbType?

Comment: `OracleDbType` should be in the ODP namespace - are you using a different provider?.  Also you are specifying a date for the parameter but then passing text.

Comment: Be sure you are referencing the correct [NuGet package for Oracle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) <= that should be the correct link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the enum [OracleDbType](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm#ODPNT2286) which is declared in both the unmanged oracle driver Oracle.DataAccess.dll and the managed one Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll.
The enum namespace is **Oracle.DataAccess.Client** in the first dll and **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client** in the second one.